# Is it ok to use the contracted version of quotationals ( 대, 래...) when you'd normally need an honorific?

Tags: honorific

Instead of saying

> 없다고 하셨어요

I think this has the same meaning:

> 없대요

However, would it normally be a problem that the honorific particle is left out? If so, is there a way of incorporating the honorific?

Comment: If it isn't related to 압존법 then in casual conversations, I could say `-대요` or `-래요` as an honorific, but I wouldn't say that unless the listener is very friendly to me, because `대요` `래요` sounds way too childish... :P I think for most of use-cases, in general, the former `없다고 하셨어요` (or maybe `없다고 해요`) works better than `없대요`.

Comment: Although it is [attested](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_owfCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT270&lpg=PT270&dq=%22%EC%97%86%EB%8B%A4%EC%85%94%22#v=onepage&q=%22%EC%97%86%EB%8B%A4%EC%85%94%22&f=false), I would also say that the contraction is not necessary when you want the honorific, and that the honorific is not felt to be necessary when you want the contracted form.

Comment: @Coconut It “sounds too childish” and you “wouldn't say that unless the listener is friendly,” **because it is not honorific.**

Comment: @Константин Ван Honorific == "존대의". Then "~대요" "~래요" may not be honorific to the person being mentioned but is still honorific to the listener... This is how I tend to listen: 1) "~다고 해" non-honorific to both the listener and the person being mentioned 2) "~다고 하셔" honorific to the person being mentioned but to the listener 3) "~다고 해요" honorific to the listener but to the person being mentioned 4) "~다고 하셔요" honorific to both people

Comment: @Coconut  You did read the question. What the OP meant by “honorific” here is one for who said the quote, not the listener. You said you “could say `-대요` or `-래요` as an honorific” and I said you cannot, in a casual conversation or not, and you know the why.

Comment: @Константин Ван Right, then I was misunderstanding it. Your point is valid, as you stated in your answer. (I put an upvote there.) But another thing is that the honorific particle is not considered that important when it's quotative. If you ask for a strict grammar then technically it should be, but in practice, it's not really a deal. In general conversations what's important is just whether the language is honorific to the listener or not (at least for me). So I did not take 'the honorific to the mentioned person' into account.

Comment: @Coconut  In my opinion, I don't want to be pedantic, but consistent and proper use of honorifics should be preferred. To me, as an answer to “그분이 뭐라고 하**시**나요?”, “굳이 그걸 할 필요가 없다(고) 하**시**네요.” sounds better than “굳이 그걸 할 필요가 없다(고 하)네요.” But you're right; it's true that honorifics for the speaker of the quote is less noticeable than ones for the direct listener, and its use depends on personal ways of talking. Understandable.

Answer (score 2):

## Constructions

#### Basic forms <sub>기본형</sub>

- Quotative, present, and non-honorific: <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없다고 하여요.”
- Quotative, present, and **honorific**: “없다고 하**시**어요.”
- Quotative, **past**, and non-honorific: <sub><sub>⚪</sub></sub>“없다고 하**였**어요.”
- Quotative, **past**, and **honorific**: “없다고 하**시었**어요.”

<sub>Bold text means it has the corresponding conjugation.</sub>

#### Contractions <sub>준말</sub>

- Quotative, present, and non-honorific: → <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없다고 **해**요.” (“-하여-” → “-해-”)
- Quotative, present, and **honorific**: → “없다고 하**셔**요.” (“-시어-” → “-셔-”)
- Quotative, **past**, and non-honorific: → <sub><sub>⚪</sub></sub>“없다고 **했**어요.”  (“-하여-” → “-해-”)
- Quotative, **past**, and **honorific**: → “없다고 하**셨**어요.”  (“-시어-” → “-셔-”)

<sub>Bold text marks where the contraction's taken place.</sub>

#### More contractions: “-고 하-”/“-고” omission. <sub>“-고 하-”/“-고” 생략</sub>

In Korean, “-고 하-” or “-고” often gets elided to contract. National Institute of Korean Language is aware of this and it's considered standard, but is not in [Standard Korean Language Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Korean_Language_Dictionary) [yet](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=113766). However, some in the dictionary reflect this: “-대” means “-다고 해” by the *standard* definition.

- Quotative, present, and non-honorific: → <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없다 해요” (“-고” omission) → <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없대요.” (“-고 하-” omission)
- Quotative, present, and **honorific**: → “없다 하셔요” (“-고” omission) → “없다셔요.” (“-고 하-” omission)
- Quotative, **past**, and non-honorific: → <sub><sub>⚪</sub></sub>“없다 했어요” (“-고” omission) → <sub><sub>⚪</sub></sub>“없댔어요.” (“-고 하-” omission)
- Quotative, **past**, and **honorific**: → “없다 하셨어요” (“-고” omission) → “없다셨어요.” (“-고 하-” omission)

> **Papers**
>
> - [‘-고 하-’의 생략과 씨끝의 융합 (Ellipsis of “-go ha-” and fusion of the endings) (2001) (ISSN 1225-0449)](https://academic.naver.com/article.naver?doc_id=11037696)
> - [A Study on the Contraction in Quotative Connective Sentences (2017) (ISSN 1229-3946)](https://academic.naver.com/article.naver?doc_id=291847660)

---

## Should it keep honorifics when contracted?

Yes.

You said you thought “없다고 하**셨**어요” has the same meaning with <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없대요,” but it's not. “없다고 하**셨**어요” is quotative, **past**, and **honorific;** <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없대요” is quotative, **present**, and **not honorific**. Not taking the tense into account, honorifics still matter. After all, they're just contractions; their forms may vary, but their meanings hold the same.

“없다고 하**셨**어요” should be contracted into either “없다 하셨어요” or “없다셨어요,” not <sub><sub>⚫</sub></sub>“없대요.”

And a note about contraction itself: this is obvious, but the more you contract, the more it gets informal. It's not that it'll sound rude, so just make sure you're in the right tense and using proper honorifics.